# Por qué no coinciden las contraseñas? password_verify

Tags: php, mysql, login

He leído ya bastantes preguntas sobre este tema pero ninguna solucionó mi problema.
Estoy haciendo un simple login con PHP y MySQL. Recién tuve un problema que la comunidad me ayudó a solucionar, pero ahora entré a este: El password_verify siempre me da false, tengo primero la variable en texto plano y la segunda es la que viene de la base de datos ya "hasheada".

```
<?php 


include("db.php");
if(!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {

    //$contra = password_hash($_POST['contraseña'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $contra = $_POST['contraseña'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE Correo = '$correo'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
        $rol = $row['Rol'];
        $correo = $row['Correo'];
        $contraDB = $row['Contraseña'];

        echo $contra."---";
        echo $contraDB;

        if (password_verify($contra, $contraDB)){ //En este if siempre me da false

            if ($rol == 1){
                header("Location: opencrud.php");
            }else {
                header("Location: closecrud.php");
            }
        }else{
            echo "La contraseña no coincide con ese correo, crack.";
        }

    }else{
        echo "Ese correo está incorrecto mi bro.";
    }
}
```

?>

Ya imprimí y modifiqué las variables para que coincidan. Usando el echo se supone que las dos valen **111** pero siempre me manda al *else*. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Este es el **Actualizar** de mi programa en donde muestra cómo encripto las contraseñas:

```
if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])){
    $Id = $_GET['Id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['Correo'];
    $contra = password_hash($_POST['contraseña'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT); // Aquí
    $rol = $_POST['Rol'];

    $query = "UPDATE registros SET nombre = '$nombre', correo = '$correo', contraseña = '$contra', rol = '$rol' WHERE Id = $Id";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Actualizado correctamente.";
    $_SESSION['message_type'] = "primary";

    header("Location: opencrud.php");
}
```

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que a `password_verify` le tienes que pasar la cadena y el hash que la encripta, también podrías simplemente "hashear" la contraseña ingresada por el usuario y solo compararla con la que ya tienes en la DB. Saludos.

Comment: No puedo 'hashear' el dato que me pasa el usuario porque cada hash es distinto, jajaja ya lo intenté y al imprimirlos me di cuenta que siempre son diferentes incluso si es el mismo dato. :(

Comment: ¿Que función utilizas para encriptar?

Comment: @JosueArriola Ahí lo agregué a la pregunta por si alguien más lo necesita.

Comment: Ahora entiendo un poco mejor, lo que debes hacer es `password_verify(valor ingresado por el usuario sin hash,el hash guardado en la db);` si quieres te comparto un pequeño ejemplo como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola Eso es lo que he tenido desde el comienzo y no me sirve :( siempre ha estado primero el valor ingresado por el usuario en plano y luego el de la DB. Me ayudaría el ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: También algo que te recomiendo que hagas es que al momento de hacer update a las contraseñas tienes que escapar los caracteres especiales, más que todo el `$`, sino puede que se guarde el pass sin todos los caracteres.

Comment: Supongo que al momento del `INSERT` guardaste la clave con `password_hash()`, ¿cierto? Ahora si no funciona, verifica **el tipo y tamaño de la columna de la BD donde guardas la clave**, ocurre a veces que ésta es muy pequeña o no es del tipo adecuado y el hash se queda truncado por ese motivo y luego la verificación no pasa. Según el algoritmo de encriptación que uses, la columna deberá tener un tamaño mínimo para que no te dé problemas. Chequea eso y me comentas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí,en la BD es un varchar de 255, lo vi en varias publicaciones y lo cambié pero me sigue dando el mismo error. Y sí, en el insert uso esa función y uso BCRYPT, no sé si influya. Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Implementa código para verificar que el `UPDATE` está ocurriendo realmente mediante una comprobación de [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php), el valor obtenido debe ser igual o mayor que `1`. Si es así, intenta declarar la columna de tipo `CHAR` en vez de `VARCHAR`, OJO: antes de cambiar estructura de la tabla haz un backup si está ya en producción.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya hice la columna de contraseña a char y me da el mismo error, mi crud, como ya mencioné funciona bien, de hecho puedo imprimir las contraseñas y me las muestra, lo que no me sirve por alguna razón, porque las muestro justo antes del if y me las muestra bien.

Comment: Debes implementar un control estricto de tu código verificando todo: que el `INSERT` y el `UPDATE` ocurren realmente, la forma de verificarlo es con `affected_rows`... En ese sentido tu código tiene lagunas (partes no cubiertas, no controladas que podrían estar fallando y no lo ves porque no hay un control estricto del flujo del código). Por ejemplo, el uso de `ñ` o acentos en elementos nominales (variables, tablas, columnas...) podría dar problemas de codificación y romper el código sin que lo percibas al no controlar ciertos posibles errores en el flujo del código.

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que ya tienes el hash guardado en la DB debes utilizarlo en la comparación, eso le dirá a `password_verify()` si las contraseñas concuerdan o no, intenta algo así:

```
<?php
$hash_db = password_hash("123456",PASSWORD_BCRYPT); /*Esto solo es para el ejemplo, tu ya lo tienes encriptado en tu DB, no debes hacerlo*/
$input = "123456";

if(password_verify($input,$hash_db)){
    echo "correcto";
}

else {
    echo "incorrecto";
   }
?>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo.

<kbd>[Ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1121c41256133120013b1eff170518e0a6876c7)</kbd>

Comment: No lo entiendo amigo, eso es exactamente lo que tengo, o sea, ya estoy comparando así, no veo mi error :(

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo hacer es generar un hash cualquiera, por ejemplo 123546, insertalo manualmente en la DB y haz la prueba de tu código de login, creo que el problema puede venir del update que estas haciendo al pass y no del login, intenta y me cuentas. Saludos.

Comment: No, eso no tiene nada que ver. Yo solo le mostré el update para que viera cómo se encriptaba la clave, todo mi crud funciona bien. Yo puedo insertar, editar, borrar y seleccionar de mi base de datos perfectamente, de hecho el singup también está perfecto. Lo único que falla es la comparación, los datos que le paso son exactamente los mismos pero uno está encriptado por BCRYPT y el otro es texto plano (ubicados de manera correcta en el if), entonces sigo sin saber qué sucede.

Comment: Solo como una medida "por si acaso" puedes poner `TRIM($_POST['contraseña']);` al momento de recibir el valor, otra cosa que se me ocurre es cambiar la `ñ` no debería causar problemas pero lo mejor será descartarlo.